# Force autorotate of view in ios 6

Tags: ios, ios6, orientation, autorotate

I want forcefully autorotate view from portrait to landscape mode in IOS 6. The view to be in landscape mode displays graphs. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Your app will get rejected if you use the method `[UIDevice setOrientation:]`. You can try to use `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` for your purpose.

Comment: Actually when the user opens the graph view, it should auto rotate to landscape. Is it wrong to do it? if not, then can you explain me how to do it ?

Comment: yes, the _Quartz2D_ transitions could help on you to achieve this.

Comment: You use `- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations` for setting the orientation of the view controller. This should autorotate the view.

Comment: this is not working. do i need to make any changes in my storyboard file also ?

Answer (score 0):

In your application’s Info.plist file, add the UIInterfaceOrientation key and set its value to the landscape mode. 
you can set the value of this key to UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft or UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight. for landscape orientations.

Override your view controller’s shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: method and return YES only for the desired landscape orientation and NO for portrait orientations.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
// Return YES for supported orientations
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

Comment: actually, i only want one of my view to be landscape mode. rest should be in portrait mode.

Comment: for rest view controllers return NO for portrait orientations.